# Insert an image into the "string" part of imagestring()

Tags: php, html, string, image

I need to output an image and I want an image inside of that. This is what I mean:

```
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  "<img src="../.."></img>", $text_color);
```

So instead of adding a string into the image I want to add a smaller image inside of it.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the HTML output you want to produce?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/30f93ce37e6b3cdfc836b41bfd867cba This is an example of an image I want to output

Answer (score 0):

this method can merge two image 
[imagecopymerge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php)

Comment: Can you give an example of this, I can't seem to make it work

Comment: this is sample of this function. test it
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ae90dd59813426e859eb21f2796bae33f2d4fc97

Comment: The only change i made was this: $img2 = imagecreatefromjpeg("apple.jpg"); but this returns a large square with a smaller (white) square in it instead of my image(the image is located in the same map as the code)

Comment: probably your image address is wrong.
please put your code here